# Java MouseListener for ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, mouselistener

How do I add a `MouseListener` to a `ComboBox`? I have tried:

```
comboBox.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ok");   
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ok");   
    }
});
```

It doesn't seems to work. I need to make the program do something when I press on the `ComboBox`, for example for typing because it is editable.

Comment: but i can add mouse listener to panel for example

Comment: With regard to `JComboBox`, you shouldn't register listeners for low-level events (e.g. mouse events). It's a *compound component*, which means that it's comprised of two or more other components.

Comment: What does "typing" have to do with a MouseListener?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse listener doesn't work with interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083022/mouse-listener-doesnt-work-with-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic swing related questions (I assume you use swing here), check the swing trail of the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).