# Mouse listener doesn't work with interface

Tags: java, swing

I'm puzzled with a strange mouse listener behavior.

First, I defined an interface :

```
public interface GeniusField {

    public void setEdited(Boolean b);

    public void addMouseListeners();
    public void addKeyListeners();

    public String getStringValue();
}
```

then, I implement this interface :

```
public class GeniusComboField extends JComboBox implements GeniusField {

    public GeniusComboField() {

        super();

        //blabla

        addMouseListeners();
        addKeyListeners();

    }

    @Override
    public void addMouseListeners() {
        System.out.println("ADD LISTENTER");

        this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("mouse mouse");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And for some reason, nothing is triggered when I click on my combobox (but I get the "ADD LISTENER" output).

I don't see what is happening.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure it's the "mouseClicked" event that would be triggered when clicking the combobok?

Comment: I tried the MouseReleased, it doesn't work. Beside I tried the mouseclicked via the design interface in netbeans and it works ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java MouseListener for ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827784/java-mouselistener-for-combobox)

Comment: @user777466 can you please to explaint for why reason you needed add MouseWhatever to the JComponent, maybe there another and more confortable way and your info can help to answering your question

Comment: Maybe you'd rather know when the combobox was changed rather than just clicked?

Comment: @Banthar That question was answered terribly.

Comment: The combobox is disabled. When the user double-click on it, it turns enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java Swing JComboBox **don't receive** the mouse events. It's the components within that do it. Try something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<this.getComponentCount(); i++) {
    this.getComponent(i).addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Then make your class implements MouseListener.

Or you can override the method to add object to your combobox and call your `addMouseListener()` method. Like that each object will have a listener.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. Still I'm not that satisfied, there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

JComboBox is a compound component, which means it's made up of two or more other components.
You shouldn't register listeners for low-level events on compound components because they wont capture them properly.

You need to implement ActionListener to get it to work.

```
public class GeniusComboField extends JComboBox implements ActionListener, GeniusField {
   . . .
}
```

More information about this is available in the swing [trail of the Java tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Comment: It's taken straight from the Swing Documentation. Is that outdated?

Comment: Swing documentation say how to handle event on JComboBox, and yes they consider using ActionListener. BUT the question asked is about use MouseListener on JComboBox not ActionListener.

Comment: Okay, I just tested this out and it looks like it doesn't trigger when the box is clicked, only after it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has to implement MouseListener( may be GeniusComboField ).
something like this.

```
public class GeniusComboField extends JComboBox implements GeniusField, MouseListener
```

Comment: Wrong, you can add listener like he did, he just add the listener on the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code. it seems to work just fine. Problem may be where your adding this combo box. The mouse listener will be for the combo box itself, not the items in it.